# Order form in product list

Tags: orders, configurable-product, product-list

I would like to add an order form to a product category list.  I have created the form manually following other posts but when I hit submit, I receive the following error: `Please specify the product's option(s).`

The following code is what I used to generate the form.  I have done a lot of low-level comparisons and cannot spot any errors. Could someone please point me in the right direction if I am off course?  Thanks in advance.

```
<ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $idx => $_product): ?>
<?php
    $attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
    $attributeSetModel->load($_product->getAttributeSetId());
    $attributeSetName  = $attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName();
?>
<li class="product-list col-md-12 <?= $_product->getAttributeText('yuleys_css_color') ?>">
    <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                <li class="active"><a href="#product-<?= $idx ?>-description">Product Description</a></li>
                <li><a href="#product-<?= $idx ?>-warranty">YULEYS&reg; Warranty</a></li>
                <li><a href="#product-<?= $idx ?>-reviews">Reviews</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="product-<?= $idx ?>-description"><?= $_product->getDescription() ?></div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="product-<?= $idx ?>-warranty"><?= $_product->getData('yuleys_warranty') ?></div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="product-<?= $idx ?>-reviews"></div>
            </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="<?= $_product->getImageUrl() ?>" alt="<?= $_product->getName() ?>">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5">
        <h1><?= $_product->getName() ?></h1>

        <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-5 product-price"><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 product-availability"><?= $this->__('Availablility') ?>: <strong><?= ($_product->getIsSalable() ? $this->__('In stock') : $this->__('Out of stock')) ?></strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 product-code"><?= $this->__('Product Code') ?>: <strong><?= $_product->getSku() ?></strong></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">

            <?php if ( $_product->isSaleable() ): ?>
                <form action="<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form" <?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
                    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="product" id="<?= $_product->getId() ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="">
                    <?php if ( $_product->getTypeId() == 'configurable'):

                        $config_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
                        $productAttributeOptions = $config_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($config_product);

                        foreach($productAttributeOptions as $attribute):
                            ?>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="attribute<?= $attribute['id'] ?>"><?= $attribute['label'] ?></label>
                            <select name="super_attribute[<?= $attribute['id'] ?>]" id="attribute<?= $attribute['id'] ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select" required="required">
                                <option value=""><?= $this->__("Select {$attribute['label']}...") ?></option>
                                <?php foreach($attribute['values'] as $val): ?>
                                    <option value="<?= $val['value_index'] ?>" price="<?= empty($val['pricing_value']) ? '0' : $val['pricing_val'] ?>"><?= $val['label'] ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        endforeach; 

                    endif;
                    ?>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="qty<?= $_product->getId() ?>">Qty</label>
                        <input name="qty" id="qty<?= $_product->getId() ?>" type="number" step="1" min="1" required="required" class="input-text qty" id="qty_<?php echo $_product->getId()?>" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getMinimalQty($_product)== null?1:$this->getMinimalQty($_product); ?>">
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></button>

                </form>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>

    </div>

</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you get the error after submitting the form on the cart or form page.

The problem is, that your product is either an configurable product or has custom options. These options/attributes need to be selected when adding the product to the cart.

[In the Magento wiki can be found more about this.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring)

> To add a simple product with custom options simply add
>   `options[id]=[value]` to the end. The basic structure is:
>
> ```
> /path/to/magento/checkout/cart/add?product=$id&qty=$qty&options[$id]=$value
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> http://magentoserver.com/checkout/cart/add?product=13&qty=1&options[12]=57
> ```
>
> For adding a Configurable Product to the Cart via Querystring you need
>   a url format like following
>
> ```
> (line broken for better readability)
> http://www.your_domain.com/checkout/cart/add
> ?product=68&qty=1&super_attribute[528]=55&super_attribute[525]=56
> ```

Comment: Thank you this makes sense, although it seems a little disheartening that I have to go through a proxy to properly form the request.  Thanks again!